# IOS: Game Center matching very slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, multiplayer

My application has a multiplayer mode and i am using the following code to find players:

```
[GKMatch ] GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 4;

[[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] findMatchForRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(GKMatch *match, NSError *error) {

    if (error)
    {
        // Process the error.
        NSLog(@"Error Match Process: %@", error);
    }
    else if (match != nil)
    {   
        DuelModeController* duelModeController = (DuelModeController*)viewController;
        [duelModeController updateSearchingMessageWith:@"     Connecting Game..."];

    }
}];
```

The code above works. The problem is it is very slow to find a player, up to 12 to 15 seconds. To test it, i am using an iPhone and IPad with two different game center accounts, both have IOS 10.2.

Would you met such situation and how did you address it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! My App duel mode deals with two players. However when taking the sample code from Apple i copied and paste both the min and max numbers of players. Min was set to 2 but Max was set to 4.

Once i have set the max number of player to 2 , find a match takes 2-3 seconds instead of the 12 to 15 seconds. My theory is game center might have been waiting to identify a third and forth player, seeing it could not find them it returns success after 12-15 seconds.

Lesson learned : when defining your number of players in the GKMatch , specify only the player numbers you want, not more.

Stephane